# SQL problem: 3 tables, requiring JOIN, COUNT, GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three (3) tables: Course, Student, Registration. The columns in each table are:

- Course: CourseNo, Title, Department, NumberOfCredits, CourseFees
- Student: SID, Name, Address, Telephone, Age
- Registration: SID, CourseNo, startDate, CompleteDate, Grade

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to write the correct statement that will list the course numbers and titles of courses that have more than 10 students getting a grade lower than 50. I'd like to be able to GROUP BY CourseNo and have a COUNT based on SID.

Any help would be much appreciated, especially if any explanation can be given.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this help

```
select c.CourseNo, c.Title, count(SID) AS sCount
  from Registration r
  join Course c on (c.CourseNo = r.CourseNo)
  where r.Grade < 50
  group by r.CourseNo
  HAVING sCount > 10;
```

Comment: That helps very much, thank you. I was doing my join wrong and as a result everything was thrown.

Comment: if an answer solve your problem, please select as an accepted answer to let them other people know this question is solved.